# How do I iteratively request user input via modalDialog in rShiny?

Tags: r, shiny, modal-dialog

I've been researching / troubleshooting this for a week and can't seem to figure out the issue.

Basically, I'd like to iteratively request user input via a dialog box in rShiny. The user uploads a file, they press run report, and if any duplicates that are identified - the user must manually determine which row to choose.

I've listed two "tries" below.

1. The first tries to `lapply` through all the identified duplicates `dups()`. Thing is, when run, it skips to the last modal dialog.
2. The second try iterates through the first dup and then pauses at req waiting for the "ok". To do so, I need to globally assign `i`; I use `<<-` which I understand is generally a big no-no. Even still, when pressing okay, it only prints the first user input and does not continue the loop. Oddly, if you press "Run Report" again, it'll skip the first option and go to the second.

Data:

```
ID,Name,Desc
1,Tom,Recent
2,Jerry,Recent
3,Frank,Recent
3,Frank,Not Recent
4,Jennifer,Recent
5,Terrence,Recent
5,Terrence,Not Recent
```

I've created a small reproducible example below.

```
shinyApp(
  ui = basicPage(
    fileInput(
      inputId = "xlsx",
      label = "Upload File here",
      multiple = TRUE,
      accept = ".xlsx"
  ),
  actionButton("runReport", "Run Report")
),

server = function(input, output) {
  # Import Dataset
  dataset <- reactive({
    read.xlsx(input$xlsx$datapath)
  })

  observeEvent(input$xlsx, {
    print(dataset())
  })

  dups <- eventReactive(input$runReport, {
    unique(dataset()$ID[duplicated(dataset()$ID) |
                          duplicated(dataset()$ID)])

  })

  # Try # 1

  lapply(
    X = 1:2,
    FUN = function(i) {
      observeEvent(dups()[[i]], {
        # Show modal in client browser
        showModal(
          # Create UI for modal dialog
          modalDialog(
            title = "Multiple Options Found: Choose One",
            DT::renderDT(DT::datatable(dataset()[dataset()$ID == dups()[[i]],])),

            numericInput(paste0("optionRow", i), "Choose Row", NULL),

            footer = tagList(modalButton("Cancel"),
                             actionButton(paste0("ok", i), "OK"))

          )
        )

      })

      observeEvent(input[[paste0("ok", i)]], {
        print(input[[paste0("optionRow", i)]]) # choice assignment
        removeModal()

      })

    }
  )

  # Try #2

  observeEvent(dups(), {
    for (i in seq_along(dups())) {
      modalInstance <- function(x) {
        # Create UI for modal dialog
        modalDialog(
          title = "Multiple Options Found: Choose One",
          DT::renderDT(DT::datatable(dataset()[dataset()$ID == dups()[[x]],])),

          numericInput(paste0("optionRow", x), "Choose Row", NULL),

          footer = tagList(modalButton("Cancel"),
                           actionButton(paste0("ok", x), "OK"))

        )
      }

      cur <- modalInstance(i)

      showModal(cur)

      i <<- i

      # Need an outside call to fulfill requirement but continue loop
      print(!is.null(input[[paste0("ok", i)]]))
      req(!is.null(input[[paste0("ok", i)]]))

    }

  })

  observeEvent(input[[paste0("ok", i)]], {
    print(input[[paste0("optionRow", i)]]) # choice assignment
    removeModal()

  })

})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a short example app with a built-in dataset that has 2 sets of duplicate rows (row #s 3 & 4 and 8 & 9). The loop is entered using reactiveValues in this example rv$loop. If the rv$loop is greater than 1 the loop continues. The 'go' button finds duplicates in the dataset and initiates a loop to test what rows are equal to the duplicate row. For each duplicate set a modalDialogue is launched showing the duplicate rows and the user can decide which rows to remove with a selectInput.

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton('go', "Go!"),
  h4("original dataframe"),
  tableOutput("original"),
  h4("user selected rows to filter out"),
  verbatimTextOutput("user_filtered"),
  h4("new user filtered df"),
  tableOutput('final')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  data <- tibble(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5),
                 Name = c("Tom", "Jerry", "Frank", "Frank", "Frank", "Jennifer", "Terrence", "Terrence", "Terrence"),
                 Desc = c("Recent", "Recent", "Recent", "Recent","Not Recent", "Recent", "Recent", "Not Recent","Not Recent" ))
  
  data_indexed <- data %>% mutate(original_row = 1:length(ID))
  
  dups <- eventReactive(input$go, {

  
  df_split <- split(data, seq(nrow(data))) 
  
  dups_locations <- duplicated(data)
  
  dups <- data[which(dups_locations == T),]
  
  out <- vector("list")
  for(i in seq_len(nrow(dups))){
    out[[i]] <- map(df_split, ~identical(.x, dups[i,]))
  }

  return(out)
})
  
  rv <- reactiveValues(loop = 0, trigger = 0)
  
  num_iterations <- reactive({length(dups())})
  
  #start loops first time
  observeEvent(dups(), {
    rv$loop <- rv$loop + 1
          })
  
  #continues loop or stops
  duplicated_data <- eventReactive(rv$loop, {
    if(rv$loop > 0){
            data_indexed[which(dups()[[rv$loop]] == T),]
    }
  })

  output$table <- renderTable({
    duplicated_data() 
  })
  
  observeEvent(duplicated_data(),{
          rv$trigger <- rv$trigger + 1
  })
  observeEvent(rv$trigger, ignoreInit = TRUE, {
      showModal(modalDialog(title = "Make a Choice!",
                            "Which one to remove?",
                            tableOutput('table'),
                            selectInput('remove', "Remove this one", choices = seq_len(nrow(duplicated_data()))),
                            footer = actionButton("modal_submit", "Submit")))
  })
  
  remove_rows <- reactiveValues()
  #when user closes modal the response is saved to           #remove_rows[[character representing number of iteration]]
  observeEvent(input$modal_submit, {
    remove_rows[[as.character(rv$loop)]] <- duplicated_data()$original_row[[as.numeric(input$remove)]]
    if(rv$loop < num_iterations()){
      rv$loop <- rv$loop + 1 #this retriggers step2 to go again
    } else {
      rv$done <- rv$done + 1
    } #breaks the disjointed loop and trigger start of next reactions
  })
  
  observeEvent(rv$done, {
    rv$loop <- 0 
  })
  
  #and the modal is closed
  observeEvent(input$modal_submit, {
    removeModal()
  })
  
  final_choice <- eventReactive(rv$done, ignoreInit = TRUE,{
    remove <- unlist(isolate(reactiveValuesToList(remove_rows)), use.names = F)
     # data[-as.numeric(remove),]
    
    
  })
  
  output$original <- renderTable({
    data
  })
  
  output$user_filtered <- renderText({
    final_choice()
  })
  
   output$final <- renderTable({
     data_indexed[-final_choice(),]
   })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE:** This is working for me using dev version of shinyalert (1.0.0.9004).

I am unsure how you would include a datatable in the alert or whats the most intuitive way to allow a user to pick the row. However, here is one example of looping through a list and showing an alert for each element using `lapply`:

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyalert)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("go", "go"),
  useShinyalert()
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$go, {
    dupes <- df[df$ID %in% df[duplicated(df$ID),]$ID, ]
    dupes_list <- split(dupes, dupes$ID)

    lapply(dupes_list, function(x) {
      shinyalert(
        title = unique(x$Name)
      )
    })
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Data:

```r
df <-
  structure(list(
    ID = c("1", "2", "3", "3", "4", "5", "5"),
    Name = c(
      "Tom",
      "Jerry",
      "Frank",
      "Frank",
      "Jennifer",
      "Terrence",
      "Terrence"
    ),
    Desc = c(
      "Recent",
      "Recent",
      "Recent",
      "Not Recent",
      "Recent",
      "Recent",
      "Not Recent"
    )
  ),
  row.names = c(NA, -7L),
  class = "data.frame")
```